# Opening two programs in a same memoryspace

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Is it possible to launch two completely independent programs into one scope of memory area?

For example, I have `skype.exe` and `opera.exe` and I want to launch them on a way that will allows them to share common memory. Sounds like threading to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are quite some questions at the same time, let me try to dissect:

- It is the definition of a process on a modern OS to have its own virtual address space. So running two processes in the same address space can't happen without a modification to the OS to allow exactly that.
- Even if such a modification were available, it would be a less than perfect idea: Access to memory shared between threads is governed by synchronisation primitives explicitly built into them. There is no such mechanism to manage memory access between two processes, that have not explicitly been designed so
- Sharing memory if so designed between processes does not at all need them to run in the same virtual address space in their totality: Shared memory segments exist in virtually all modern OS to facilitate exactly that. Again, those processes have to be explicitly designed to use this feature.

Comment: Tell that to Cheat Engine, which can write/read directly from a memory address of any process. I think this is possible. Some sort of IPC or something.

Comment: Any program authorized by the OS can access any real (a.o.t. virtual) address - this is e.g. the way a debugger works. But nevertheless the cheat engine (or the debugger) runs in its own process and vas.

Comment: This is not a problem. All am I asking for is is it possible for one to open two programs in the same virtual memory. I know this depends much from the OS, but I also know that C is powerful enough in system level to accomplish something like that.

Comment: The programming language has nothing to do with it - memory mapping is an OS function, independant of the language used to write the process.

Comment: Such function can be activated through code I believe. At least through assembler.

Comment: Again: It has nothing to do with whatever programming language you use. Mapping memory and granting access to it is an OS function, that is invoked via the OS API after authorization to do so. If this were not the case, any running program could completely spy on, alter and corrupt every other program's memory.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask another question later. Asking how two programs can communicate to each other without 3rd party library OR with 3rd party program that is free to use any library.

Comment: This one is easy: First take a look at mailslots, then at named pipes (assuming you use Windows): Free and compatible with all WIndows versions

Comment: thank you. Yes. yes I am unfortunately using Windows. Seems I will have to check many things. MPI, mailslots, named pipes..

Answer (score 0):

If they are two independent programs running then you have to ensure that the data is passed in an independent way between them. Let's say the two programs are running, the first program compute some data that the second program needs. The simplest thing to do is print the data from the first program into a file with some status at the end of the file (to indicate that it is safe for the other program to start reading it). From the other program you have a while loop that checks the status of the last line in that file every period of time.

The other option is to use some library like MPI which has protocols for message passing implemented.

Comment: I will learn more about MPI thanks. Though, file i/o is slow for immediate events.

Comment: If you want immediate events on Windows (as I take from skype **.exe**) use mailslots for the easiest learning curve.

Comment: mailslots? This sounds interesting. What is it?